# Polynomial class Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make two methods for a Polynomial class but I'm having troubles.
The first method checkZeros is supposed to check if there are any leading zeros in the coefficients of a polynomial. The method should resize the coefficient array if there are leading zeros. The second method should find the derivative of a polynomial, but I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds errors.

Here they are:

```
public class Poly {

private float[] coefficients;
public static void main (String[] args){
    float[] fa = {3, 2, 4};
    Poly test = new Poly(fa);

}

public Poly() {
    coefficients = new float[1];
    coefficients[0] = 0;
}

public Poly(int degree) {
    coefficients = new float[degree+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        coefficients[i] = 0;
}


public Poly(float[] a) {
    coefficients = new float[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        coefficients[i] = a[i];
}

public int getDegree() {
    return coefficients.length-1;
}

public float getCoefficient(int i) {
    return coefficients[i];
}

public void setCoefficient(int i, float value) {
    coefficients[i] = value;
}

public Poly add(Poly p) {
    int n = getDegree();
    int m = p.getDegree();
    Poly result = new Poly(Poly.max(n, m));
    int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= Poly.min(n, m); i++) 
            result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i] + p.getCoefficient(i));
        if (i <= n) {
            //we have to copy the remaining coefficients from this object
            for ( ; i <= n; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i]);
        } else {
            // we have to copy the remaining coefficients from p
            for ( ; i <= m; i++) 
                result.setCoefficient(i, p.getCoefficient(i));
        }
    return result;
}

public void displayPoly () {
    for (int i=0; i < coefficients.length; i++)
        System.out.print(" "+coefficients[i]);
    System.out.println();
}

private static int max (int n, int m) {
    if (n > m)
        return n;
    return m;
}

private static int min (int n, int m) {
    if (n > m)
        return m;
    return n;
}


public void checkForZeros(){
   int newDegree = getDegree();
   int length = coefficients.length;
   double testArray[] = coefficients;

   for (int i = length - 1; i >0; i--) {
      if (coefficients[i] != 0) {
       testArray[i] = coefficients[i];

        } 
   }

   for (int j = 0; j < testArray.length; j++){
       coefficients[j] = testArray[j];
   } 
}    


public Poly differentiate(){
   int n = getDegree();
   int newPolyDegree = n - 1;
   Poly newResult = new Poly();

   if (n == 0){
       newResult.setCoefficient(0, 0);
   }
   for (int i =0; i<= n; i++){
      newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i+1] * (i+1));
 }
   return newResult;
   }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error on? The stacktrace should tell you. In fact, post the stacktrace here instead of just typing which error you got.

Comment: If you remove ALL the zeroes from the array, (which is what your `checkForZeroes` is doing), you end up with an entirely different polynomial.  I don't think you should be doing this.

Comment: In any case, there's not enough information here to properly diagnose your issue.  Perhaps you could post your whole `Poly` class?  I suspect there are actually quite a few bugs in it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry, I edited to add my Poly class. Didn't want to put too much code as people don't like going through all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the problem is here

```
   for (int i =0; i<= n; i++){
      newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i+1] * (i+1));
   }
```

Since `n = getDegree();`, let's assume the polynomial is of 1st degree (1+x for example). Then n=1 I would guess, and coefficients has a length of 2. But you are going to be checking coefficients[2] (since you have i+1) which is out of bounds. I'm guessing you want

```
   for (i=0; i<=newPolyDegree; i++){
      newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i] * (i+1));
   }
```

or something... It's hard to tell with the amount of code you gave.

Comment: Actually it's `coefficient[i+1]*(i+1)` for differentiation anyway, the loop bound should be changed `i=0;i<=newPolyDegree;i++`

Comment: @v3ga - Right, that makes sense because we are getting the derivative, updated my answer.

Comment: @user2980566 - Sure thing, if this was the issue please let everyone know by selecting it as correct and/or voting it up.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably getting ArrayIndexOutofBounds because you've implemented checkzeroes in a wrong manner and hence getdegree() is returning a size less than the coefficient array. Consider the following polynomial:
f(x) = 2x^3 + 5x + 1
The coefficient array will be
[2,0,5,1]
After checkzeroes, it becomes
[2,5,1] (because you're removing all zeroes, not just leading zeroes.)
I suppose the degree function will still return 3 and you'll run out of array bounds in differentiate()

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the loop.

```
for (int i =0; i<= n; i++){
      newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i+1] * (i+1));
```

Base on little information, I assume:
1. setCoefficient(power of x, coefficient of x)

So in this case, we have a polynomial of degree n for differentiation, which have n+1 term, starting from 0->n (x^0 -> x^n)
Look at the loop, when i=n, it have to fetch the coefficient of x^(n+1) which is not exist.
You should do.

```
for (int i =0; i< n; i++){
      newResult.setCoefficient(i, coefficients[i+1] * (i+1));
```